# Apex predators in fantasy

Tags: biology, evolution, fauna, fantasy-races

This is a topic I've looked up considerably, but I don't think I've ever seen it discussed (it probably exists somewhere, but I've never seen it). Anyways, in worlds with creatures like dragons and other mythical beasts, how do they compete with other animals?

Comment: Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. To that end, questions should be narrowly constrained and ask only one question at a time. Developing a fully detailed ecosystem is far outside the scope of our Q&A format. Further, there are four distinct questions here, a red flag for having a question be put on hold as _too broad_. I would strongly suggest narrowing your topic of interest.

Comment: Thanks for focusing on one question!  After you've gotten some answers to this question, please feel free to consider your other questions and perhaps revisit them in similar fashion.  (Don't forget to link to link to this question so people can get an idea what's already been discussed.)

Comment: Please clarify:  are your dragons crafty and intelligent *persons* (like Smaug) or are they just jumped up lizards, beasts mindlessly seeking prey?

Comment: *"In worlds with creatures like dragons and other mythical beasts, how do they compete with other animals?"* They compete fiercely, of course. Unless it's a book for children, in which case they don't compete at all, but rather coöperate peacefully.

Comment: @elemtilas They're essentially descendants of dinosaurs that didn't go extinct and have a connection to magic. I'd say their intelligence is around that of a raven (which are fairly smart birds). I also probably should've mentioned their size. Most would probably be slightly larger than a T-Rex, though they keep growing throughout their life and can potentially reach sizes comparable to baleen whales (this would be incredibly rare).

Comment: So...basically big chickens!

Comment: @elemtilas Pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

**Depends on the rarity and type of other creatures**

This actually is brought up in the end of *Inheritance* (The Inheritance Cycle, by Christopher Paolini) when discussing the dragon's hunting ground. Dragon's ability vary, depending on the setting, but they're generally capable of a few things. Flight, breath weapons, claws, hard scales, and massive size. Humans armed with very powerful and dangerous weapons don't do well against dragons, typically you need a Hero of some sort, though in a pinch a Burglar with an eye for weak points will do just fine. In Inheritance, the other magical and mythical beasts are nowhere near the might of a dragon, so they need to fight deserted areas.

Nothing in the natural world beats a dragon in a normal world, so they become apex predators to a ridiculous degree. Remember, they also possess the ability to fly, so their hunting range becomes absolutely massive - possibly even hundreds of miles. And there'd be very few of them. The general rule is that as you go higher up the food chain, the smaller the species will be, so there are typically far more prey than there are predators (notable exception being *Homo Sapiens*, naturally). If I had to guess the social structure, I'd model it after a real life apex predator, like the lion - they would live in a small group with one dominant male and a few mates, except instead of dividing the Sub-Sahara for territory, they'd carve up the world. Of course, that's one such example, any apex predator would serve as a good model.

Unless these dragon live in a fantasy world, as which point all bets are off. You did say mythical beasts, and depending on the type, dragons would merely just be another predator. Seriously. There are basilisks and cockatrices, which can turn things to stone with a glare, manticores which can penetrate armor and paralyze with a touch using poison spikes, gargoyles made entirely from stone, salamanders which lives in volcanoes and are immune to fire and not to mention the humans with magic. At that point, honestly they're just a giant lizard which can fly and has a breath attack. In a setting like Lord of the Rings, which has rare magic and few magical creatures, dragons are absolutely terrifying. Something like, say, *Inheritance Cycle*? They can be killed using the twelve words of death like any other creature by a competent enough mage.

Comment: What is 'Inheritance'?

Comment: @MorrisTheCat Series beginning with [Eragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon).